# How to remove quotation marks from string Dart

Tags: string, flutter, dart

I want to remove the quotation mark from the string. in dart

EX : **"26f8076e-8808-4f1e-9056-589bc92bfd81"**

need in : **26f8076e-8808-4f1e-9056-589bc92bfd81**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: double inverted comma? you mean quotation mark?

Comment: Yes yes, quotation marks

Comment: I really like the name "double inverted comma"

Comment: Why you want that?

Comment: this is the kind of token I have to attach to the web url.

Answer (score 4):

You can replace Double inverted comma OR Double quotation marks with empty as below.

```
 void main() {
      String id = '"26f8076e-8808-4f1e-9056-589bc92bfd81"';
      String filteredString = id.replaceAll('"', '');
      print(filteredString);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code and use [**`replaceAll`**](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/String/replaceAll.html) method

```
void main() {
  String yourString = "26f8076e-8808-4f1e-9056-589bc92bfd81";
  print(yourString.replaceAll('"', '\\"'));
}
```

Result:  `26f8076e-8808-4f1e-9056-589bc92bfd81`

You can test above code on [dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/)

Answer (score 0):

You should take care to only replace the leading and trailing quotation marks.

```
String result = yourString.replaceAll(RegExp(r'^\"|\"$'), "");
```

Answer (score -1):

```
String x =  "26f8076e-8808-4f1e-9056-589bc92bfd81";
 x.replaceAll('"','');
```

Comment: This won't replace anything

Comment: tried but not working.

Comment: x.replaceAll("\"","");